# Retrieving the Unstandardised coefficients from a Standardised Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, standardization

Is it possible to retrieve the Unstandardised Regression Coefficients from a Standardised Regression? If so, how is does one do this in order to use the coefficients to make predictions on new data?

If not, how can one interpret the results from a standardised regression and use them to make predictions on unstandardised data? Do I standardise the new data with its own mean and standard deviation or with the original mean and standard deviations?

Many thanks!

EDIT: These two links have been a large part of my research. They are very helpful but do not detail anything about de-standardising or interpreting the results.

[When to standardise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-should-you-center-your-data-when-should-you-standardize)

[How to standardise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13267/how-to-sum-two-variables-that-are-on-different-scales/13271#13271)

Answer (score 1):

In order to "unstandardize" a coefficient you  multiply that coefficients with the standard deviation of that variable.

Comment: So should this give the same answer as if I were to run a regression without having standardised initially?